# Providing stubbed files via URLs in junit tests - wiremock

Tags: java, junit, wiremock

**Scenario we have:-**

We have a Module (in java) to test with Junit. The module basically takes files as input, processes them and then writes data to the Hazelcast. These input files are downloaded from a internal URL.

In our Junit Test (completely a separate test project i.e. junit test does not reside in the mudule to be tested), **we do not have access to this URL where these files are residing.**

**Problem:-**

-> In order to provide input files to the Module, .properties file is used in which it is specified wehre it is physically located. which is InputFileUrl field in the Module itself.

-> Somewhere in Module, this Url will be read (from .properties file) and then some extra parameters will be added to it. and then the module tries to call this the Url and downloads the input files. From Test project we dont have access to this URL. so we provide these input files with following Static address of the file:

```
InputFileUrl = file:///C:/Inputs/file.xml
```

-> The problem is, when some extra Parameters are added to above URL in the Module, naturally it becomes unvalid URL and throws exception. We could successfully run the Module from our Test Project if we make the part of the Module comments where these extra parameters are added. (just one line commnet)

So 
1) how can we solve this URL Access problem without changing the Module code itself ?

Can WireMock technology be useful here ? I read about it a bit and not sure if it can be useful forn this scenario since here the internal URL to be mocked for the Module under Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with Wiremock you can set up a stub server that responds with the xml you want to provide to your module. So for the test you would set up

```
InputFileUrl = http://<wiremockurl>
```

wiremockurl is typically "localhost", though you can run wiremock standalone with a fixed IP / domainname.

Stubbing then works like this:

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/api/specific-resource"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
        .withBody("<xml1>..<xml1>")));
```

As you can read in the [wiremock documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/), you can either return the same response for many additional query parameters, or setup a specific response for specific additional query parameters.

```
// responds with same response regardless of query params
.urlEqualTo("/myurl\?.*")

// responds with special xml if additional query param "search_term" is present and matches given regex
.withQueryParam("search_term", matches("^(.*)wiremock([A-Za-z]+)$"))
```

You can setup wiremock to respond with same or different properties in case the module adds extra URL parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your response tkruse. But I am just wondering what will happen when in Module itself, extra parameters will be added to the URL ? I mean the method in Module for e.g. getInputFileUrl() will return my mocked URL and then the method will try to ad extra parameters to that (as per the code of the method in Module). How do I control/avoid that from my test ? getInputFileUrl is not called from my test explicitly but is called somewhere internally...

Comment: I added more details